# i need to write a program using only the main method to calculate if triangles are congruent

Tags: java

I need to write a program using only the main method to calculate if triangles are congruent,
using boolean if triangles are congruent it will give me true
else it gives me false.

**Question**

please if someone can help me with the writing I will Appreciate

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - Please take the [tour]

Comment: "can help me with the writing". most interesting way to say "Will you pleas do my homework for me?" I've seen so far

Comment: you just do copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Congruent
{
    public static void main(String[] args){

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Please enter 6 pair of coordinates ");
    System.out.println("Please enter x1: ");
    int x1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter y1: ");
    int y1 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter x2: ");
    int x2 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter y2: ");
    int y2 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter x3: ");
    int x3 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter y3: ");
    int y3 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter x4: ");
    int x4 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter y4: ");
    int y4 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter x5: ");
    int x5 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter y5: ");
    int y5 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter x6: ");
    int x6 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter y6: ");
    int y6 = scan.nextInt();

    double AB = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1, 2) + (Math.pow(y2-y1, 2)));
    double AC = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x3-x1, 2) + (Math.pow(y3-y1, 2)));
    double BC = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x3-x2, 2) + (Math.pow(y3-y2, 2)));
    double DE = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x5-x4, 2) + (Math.pow(y5-y4, 2)));
    double DF = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x6-x4, 2) + (Math.pow(y6-y4, 2)));
    double EF = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x5-x6, 2) + (Math.pow(y5-y6, 2)));

    if((AB==DE || AB==DF || AB==EF) && (AC==DE || AC==DF || AC==EF) && (BC==DE || BC==DF || BC==EF))
        System.out.println("The triangles are congruent.");

    else
        System.out.println("The triangles are not congruent.");

}
```

}